# Cannot install sample data

Tags: theme, configuration, magento2.1.6

I'm new to magento and it's already freaking me out! Not just is it slow but nothing actually seems to work like it does on tutorials/YT videos.

So, i installed magento 2.1.6 but somehow the sample data would be installed. After some research and tries, after i checked my customer view it looks like this:

[image: I have no idea what] i did wrong, neither why the sample data nor any other theme won't work properly, if anyone knows or faced the same issue, please help me!
I'm working locally, so i have xampp installed.

*EDIT: YES I WANT TO REMOVE THE RED LINES?! but dont know how...

Comment: please confirm whether you want to disable the  template hints (red color lines) ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have a setting enabled “Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront”.

Follow the steps to disable it:

1.login as admin

2.stores->configuration.

3.Advanced->developer

4.Here you will find a setting as Debug

5.click on "Debug" you see that following tab are present:

-Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront

-Enabled Template Path Hints for Admin

-Add Block Names to Hints

6.Currently “Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront” would be enabled which is why you are getting those red lines. So all you have to do this is to simply disable this setting.Just do this Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront=no.

7.save the setting and refresh the Main Website where you were getting this error. You will notice that those red lines are gone.

Hope this answer was helpful.